# C# checkbox event in asp.net mvc view not inside form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, view, partial-views

So I have a project to make an online shop between users (post a product, buy, etc.) using a database and I'm stuck at the shopping cart view: so far I managed to show all selected (to buy) products in the shopping cart with a checked checkbox next to every single one - unchecking that box will mean that the user doesn't want to buy that product and that will remove it from the cart and back to the front page (where all products waiting to be sold are).

Product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public int OwnerID { get; set; } //the guy who posted the product

    public int? UserID { get; set; } //if someone added the product to his cart, and if the checkbox is unchecked it will be null again and removed from cart

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; } //name of product

    [Display(Name = "Short Description")]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Long Description")]
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; } //if the item was bought
}
```

Cart view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstProject.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShoppingCart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>

@if (Model == null)
{
    <div style="float:left">Your cart is empty.</div>
    <div>
        Total payment: 0
    </div>
}
else
{
    decimal tPrice = 0;
    <table style="float:left">
        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {
            tPrice = tPrice + product.Price;                
            @Html.Partial("ProductLine", product)            
        }
    </table>
    <div>
        Total payment: @tPrice
    </div>
}
```

Partial view of line in cart:

```
@model MyFirstProject.Models.Product

<tr>
    <td>        
        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-number="@Model.UserID" @*failed attempt to understand it*@
               id="UserID" name="UserID" type="checkbox" value="true"> @Model.Title        
    </td>        
    <td>           
         @Model.Price.ToString()
    </td>    
</tr>
```

My controller (relevant code):

```
using MyFirstProject.Models;
using MyFirstProject.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyFirstProject.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingController : Controller
    {
        private ShopContext db = new ShopContext();

        // GET: User
        public ActionResult Index(Product product=null)
        {
            List<Product> tempList = new List<Product>();
            if (product != null)
            {
                foreach (var p in db.Products.ToList())
                {
                    if (p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                    {
                        p.UserID = 0;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach(var p in db.Products.ToList())
            {
                if (p.UserID == null || p.State == 1)
                {
                    tempList.Add(p);
                }
            }
            return View(tempList.ToList());
        }


        public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
        {
            List<Product> toCart = new List<Product>();
            foreach (var product in db.Products.ToList())
            {
                if (product.UserID == 0)
                {
                    toCart.Add(product);
                }
            }
            return View(toCart.ToList());
        }        
    }
}
```

Long story short - how do I make check box events not inside a form that will change parameters in the database?

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to keep in the checkbox's data attribute is the product id ( or a unique id for a specific product + size +color combination)

```
<td>        
   <input checked="checked" class="cartItem" data-productId="@Model.ProductID "
                                  type="checkbox" value="true" > 
   @Model.Title        
</td>
```

Now in javascript, we will listen to the `change` event of the checkbox and make an ajax call to the server to remove it. We will use jQuery to do this.

```
$(function(){
  $(".cartItem).change(function(e){
     var _this=$(this);
     var productId=_this.data("productId");
     $.post("@Url.Action("RemoveItem","Cart")?productId="+productId,function(re){

         //redirect now
         window.location.href="@Url.Action("Index","Cart")";
     });
  });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called RemoveItem in CartController and it accepts a `productId` and remove the prouduct from the cart.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveItem(int productId)
{
  // to do :Remove from cart
  return Json(new { status="success"});
}
```